# AWS Data Transfer USE1-USW2-AWS-Out-Bytes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, data-transfert-cost

newbie question here,

I have files on S3 and am using CloudFront to offset cost when those files are accessed on the internet but I have a big ***Data Transfer USE1-USW2-AWS-Out-Bytes*** cost.

I am in the east region and created my bucket in the **us-east-1** region.
Would it help if I created a replication on my **east-1 bucket** for the **us-west-2** region so that the files can be accessed from the **west-2 region bucket**?
Or just recreate the bucket in the west-2 region ?
Or is there a better solution to *lower* the ***Data Transfer USE1-USW2-AWS-Out-Bytes*** *cost*?
Thanks

**UPDATE**
**Data Transfer**
*US East (N. Virginia)*
AWS Data Transfer USE1-USW2-AWS-Out-Bytes                $0.57
$0.02 per GB - US East (Northern Virginia) data transfer to US West (Oregon)        28.465 GB       $0.57
*Bandwidth*                                                 $1,867.71
$0.000 per GB - data transfer in per month                      20.706 GB   $0.00
$0.000 per GB - data transfer out under the monthly global free tier            100.000 GB      $0.00
$0.085 per GB - next 40 TB / month data transfer out                    11,130.664 GB       $946.11
$0.090 per GB - first 10 TB / month data transfer out beyond the global free tier   10,240.000 GB       $921.60

*US West (Oregon)*
Bandwidth      $0.00
$0.090 per GB - first 10 TB / month data transfer out beyond the global free tier   0.000000350 GB      $0.00

**CloudFront**
*Bandwidth*                                                 $752.79
$0.020 per GB - All data transfer out to Origin (US)                    0.000144 GB     $0.00
$0.085 per GB - first 10 TB / month data transfer out                   8,856.339 GB        $752.79

Comment: Is that showing up under S3 billing category or CloudFront? If S3, then I think you have bucket replication enabled or something.

Comment: @MarkB I added an update. The infos are showing under billing (detailed bill)

Comment: Your `USE1-USW2-AWS-Out-Bytes` cost is only 57c. Your big cost is `data transfer out from US-East-1`, which means to the Internet ($921.60) and also CloudFront ($752.79). The first one must be serving directly to the Internet rather than going via CloudFront. Your problem is basically that you seem to have a popular site, with lots of data being served to the Internet!

Comment: thanks for explanation, So I have no option if I want to bring the cost down? 8(